Gift Aid Already Claimed
Gift Aid has been claimed outside of CiviCRM till now. I have identified the relevant contributions.
I was hoping to add them to a Gift Aid batch and generate a report to flag them all as claimed, and throw the report away.
My assumption was that it would then be possible to run future reports only on GA that hadn't already been claimed.
However, the only option I seem to have is to export the report, but not "create claim" or "update contributions as claimed".
Does Civi not have the kind of functions that I assumed?
In future is the only option to search only for contributions with a blank GA batch?
Thanks

If you place al the contributions into a gift aid batch then they will not be included in any future batches. If you're worried about accidentally sending them for claiming then export them and this will also mark as claimed.

Thank you.I've tested and confirmed that it's not possible to add to a batch once already in a batch, but I am not clear on where a contribution is marked as claimed.
